# The argument type 'void Function()? Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(int?)?' after null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I want to migrate my flutter app to null safety and I have this error

> The argument type 'void Function()? Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(int?)?' in "OnTap: handleItemSelected,

```
_NavigationBarItem(
            index: 0,
            lable: 'Messages',
            icon: CupertinoIcons.bubble_left_bubble_right_fill,
            isSelected: (selectedIndex == 0),
            onTap: handleItemSelected,
          ),
```

this mis my HandleItemSelected void

```
 void handleItemSelected(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = index;
    });
    widget.onItemSelected!(index);
  }
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Your index argument should be a nullable integer i.e. void handleItemSelected(int? index) {...}

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this:

```
    Radio<int>(
       value: 0,
       groupValue: gvalue,
       onChanged: handleChange,
   ),



void handleChange(int? value) {
    setState(() {
      gvalue = value!;
      print(gvalue);
    });
```